# PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have the following array structure:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [configuration_id] => 10
                    [id] => 1
                    [optionNumber] => 3
                    [optionActive] => 1
                    [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [configuration_id] => 9
                    [id] => 1
                    [optionNumber] => 2
                    [optionActive] => 1
                    [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [configuration_id] => 8
                    [id] => 1
                    [optionNumber] => 1
                    [optionActive] => 1
                    [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
                )
    )
```

What is the best way to order the array in an incremental way, based on the `optionNumber`?

So the results look like:

```
Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [configuration_id] => 8
                    [id] => 1
                    [optionNumber] => 1
                    [optionActive] => 1
                    [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [configuration_id] => 9
                    [id] => 1
                    [optionNumber] => 2
                    [optionActive] => 1
                    [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [configuration_id] => 10
                    [id] => 1
                    [optionNumber] => 3
                    [optionActive] => 1
                    [lastUpdated] => 2010-03-17 15:44:12
                )
    )
```

Answer (score 253, accepted):

Use [`usort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php).

```
function cmp_by_optionNumber($a, $b) {
  return $a["optionNumber"] - $b["optionNumber"];
}

...

usort($array, "cmp_by_optionNumber");
```

---

In PHP ≥5.3, you should use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) instead:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['optionNumber'] - $b['optionNumber'];
});
```

Note that both code above assume `$a['optionNumber']` is an integer. Use [@St. John Johnson's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477532/224671) if they are strings.

---

In PHP ≥7.0, use the [spaceship operator `<=>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php/31298778#31298778) instead of subtraction to prevent overflow/truncation problems.

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['optionNumber'] <=> $b['optionNumber'];
});
```

Comment: That doesn't really helpe me as usort requires I provide it a function to use - which is the difficult bit I can't get my head round

Comment: Well he just gave you the function to use. And you're going to have to accept that there's not always a built-in function to do what you want, you have to write it yourself. Comparison functions just require a return of 1, 0, or -1 indicating the sort order for two elements.

Comment: I looked further into usort and it is actually quite cool.

I wrote a simple comparison function to the one above, however missed out the '=='.

Thanks for the help guys

Comment: Not totally sure, but I believe that if you have floats here you might run into trouble. For example, if a was 3 and b was 2.5 they would be compared as equal.

Comment: Now also as closure:-- usort($array, function($a,$b){ return $b["optionNumber"] - $a["optionNumber"]; });

Comment: `return $a["optionNumber"] - $b["optionNumber"]` does not sort floats correctly, it should be `return $a["optionNumber"] < $b["optionNumber"] ? -1 : 1` as the return value is casted to int by `usort`

Comment: In their suggested edit [gorillagoat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6683084/gorillagoat) added: Use `uksort()` to keep your original keys intact.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That work for me. But i can't understand how that's works. I'm in PHP 5.6, then i used anonymous function.
but how substract a with b can sort my array :O

Comment: @KiloumapL'artélon If the result is `< 0`, it tells the sort function that `a` should appear before `b`. If it is `> 0` then `b` should appear before `a`.

Comment: @kennytm How can i do the two time sorting with different key?

Comment: And to those who want to sort by DESC, just switch `$a` and `$b`

Comment: Best solution imo, only difference is that I use `uasort()` instead of `usort()` to keep keys :)

Comment: usort on sub array value may affect on output buffering by ob_start

Answer (score 67):

Use `usort`

```
 usort($array, 'sortByOption');
 function sortByOption($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a['optionNumber'], $b['optionNumber']);
 }
```

Comment: @BenSinclair, that's because Kenny's solution is for numbers, this solution is for strings. They are both correct :-) +1 for this alternative.

Comment: For case insensitive sort use strcasecmp instead of strcmp

Comment: can we define key for second order in array means we do first sorting with optionNumber then sorting with lastUpdated. How can do this thing?

Answer (score 20):

Using array_multisort(), array_map()

```
array_multisort(array_map(function($element) {
      return $element['optionNumber'];
  }, $array), SORT_ASC, $array);

print_r($array);
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/S5dBj)

Comment: This just works very easily. Thank you. All I had to do was change my column name and it worked.

Comment: This also preserves keys for the parent array

Comment: I know this question is a bit old by now, but I have a question: I saw that it does work, but how does it work? I've read the array_multisort docs at php.net and this still doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: this is best answer that don't affect on buffet output by ob_start. thanks.

Answer (score 19):

I used both solutions by [KennyTM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224671/kennytm) and [AJ Quick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/433736/aj-quick) and came up with a function that can help in this issue for many cases like **using ASC or DESC** sorting or **preserving keys** or if you have **objects as children of array**.

Here is this function (works for PHP7 and higher because of spaceship operator):

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param string $value
 * @param bool $asc - ASC (true) or DESC (false) sorting
 * @param bool $preserveKeys
 * @return array
 * */
function sortBySubValue($array, $value, $asc = true, $preserveKeys = false)
{
    if ($preserveKeys) {
        $c = [];
        if (is_object(reset($array))) {
            foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
                $b[$k] = strtolower($v->$value);
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
                $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$value]);
            }
        }
        $asc ? asort($b) : arsort($b);
        foreach ($b as $k => $v) {
            $c[$k] = $array[$k];
        }
        $array = $c;
    } else {
        if (is_object(reset($array))) {
            usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value, $asc) {
                return $a->{$value} == $b->{$value} ? 0 : ($a->{$value} <=> $b->{$value}) * ($asc ? 1 : -1);
            });
        } else {
            usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value, $asc) {
                return $a[$value] == $b[$value] ? 0 : ($a[$value] <=> $b[$value]) * ($asc ? 1 : -1);
            });
        }
    }

    return $array;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
sortBySubValue($array, 'optionNumber', true, false);
```

---

**Edit**

The first part can be rewritten using [`uasort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) and the function will be shorter (works for PHP7 and higher because of spaceship operator):

```
/**
 * @param array $array
 * @param string $value
 * @param bool $asc - ASC (true) or DESC (false) sorting
 * @param bool $preserveKeys
 * @return array
 * */
function sortBySubValue($array, $value, $asc = true, $preserveKeys = false)
{
    if (is_object(reset($array))) {
        $preserveKeys ? uasort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value, $asc) {
            return $a->{$value} == $b->{$value} ? 0 : ($a->{$value} <=> $b->{$value}) * ($asc ? 1 : -1);
        }) : usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value, $asc) {
            return $a->{$value} == $b->{$value} ? 0 : ($a->{$value} <=> $b->{$value}) * ($asc ? 1 : -1);
        });
    } else {
        $preserveKeys ? uasort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value, $asc) {
            return $a[$value] == $b[$value] ? 0 : ($a[$value] <=> $b[$value]) * ($asc ? 1 : -1);
        }) : usort($array, function ($a, $b) use ($value, $asc) {
            return $a[$value] == $b[$value] ? 0 : ($a[$value] <=> $b[$value]) * ($asc ? 1 : -1);
        });
    }
    return $array;
}
```

Comment: To make this work for me, I had to use `>` (greater than) instead of `-` (minus) when comparing `$a` and `$b` values since I was comparing strings.  Still works though.

Comment: @James you are right. I changed the answer and added the use of spaceship operator (<=>). Now it should work just fine.

Comment: Is there a way to make this case insensitive?

Answer (score 4):

The keys are removed when using a function like the ones above. If the keys are important, the following function would maintain it... but foreach loops are pretty inefficient.

```
function subval_sort($a,$subkey) {
    foreach($a as $k=>$v) {
        $b[$k] = strtolower($v[$subkey]);
    }
    asort($b);
    foreach($b as $key=>$val) {
        $c[$key] = $a[$key];
    }
    return $c;
}
$array = subval_sort($array,'optionNumber');
```

Use arsort instead of asort if you want from high to low.

Code credit: http://www.firsttube.com/read/sorting-a-multi-dimensional-array-with-php/

Answer (score 4):

The two most modern, most concise approaches are:

1. `usort()` with arrow function syntax and a spaceship (3-way comparison) operator. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tEkXd))

   ```
   usort($array, fn($a, $b) =>
       $a['optionNumber'] <=> $b['optionNumber']
   );
   ```

   `$a <=> $b` gives ascending sorting; `$b <=> $a` gives descending sorting.
2. `array_multisort()` with an `array_column()` call to isolate the value to compare. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/s9auZ))

   ```
   array_multisort(
       array_column($array, 'optionNumber'),
       $array
   );
   ```

   It is not necessary to include the sorting direction flag because ascending is the default/implied direction when omitted.

---

Both approaches above require the targeted array column to exist in all rows, or the approach will fail/break/error.

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.3+

```
usort($array, function($a,$b){ return $a['optionNumber']-$b['optionNumber'];} );
```

Answer (score 0):

A one-line solution using `array_multisort` and `array_column`.

```
//your array
$yourarray = Array
          (
           "0" => Array
                  (
                    "configuration_id" => 10,
                    "id" => 1,
                    "optionNumber" => 3,
                    "optionActive" => 1,
                    "lastUpdated" => "2010-03-17 15:44:12"
                  ),
           "1" => Array
                  (
                    "configuration_id" => 9,
                    "id" => 1,
                    "optionNumber" => 2,
                    "optionActive" => 1,
                    "lastUpdated" => "2010-03-17 15:44:12"
                  ),
           "2" => Array
                  (
                    "configuration_id" => 8,
                    "id" => 1,
                    "optionNumber" => 1,
                    "optionActive" => 1,
                    "lastUpdated" => "2010-03-17 15:44:12"
                  )
);

//access optionNumber in the child arrays using array_column
array_multisort(array_column($yourarray, 'optionNumber'), SORT_ASC, $yourarray);

//print out preformatted
echo "<pre>"; print_r($images); echo "</pre>";
```