# PHP sort array alphabetically using a subarray value

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I sort arrays and data in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php)
>   [How do I sort a multidimensional array in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/96759/how-do-i-sort-a-multidimensional-array-in-php)
>   [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value)
>   [PHP sort multidimensional array by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/php-sort-multidimensional-array-by-value)

My array looks like:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
         [name] => Bill
         [age] => 15
    ),
    [1] => Array(
         [name] => Nina
         [age] => 21
    ),
    [2] => Array(
         [name] => Peter
         [age] => 17
    )
);
```

I would like to sort them in alphabetic order based on their name.
I saw [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value) but it didn't help much.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: The question you linked contains the exact answer you need.. just replace `'optionNumber'` with `'name'` in the comparison function. Voting to close as duplicate. If there's something in the other question you don't understand please ask specifically about that.

Comment: I've never seen an array that has the same key for two values. Probably that's why the sort does not work?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Here is your answer and it works 100%, I've tested it.

```
<?php
$a = Array(
    1 => Array(
         'name' => 'Peter',
         'age' => 17
    ),
    0 => Array(
         'name' => 'Nina',
         'age' => 21
    ),
    2 => Array(
         'name' => 'Bill',
         'age' => 15
    ),
);
function compareByName($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}
usort($a, 'compareByName');
/* The next line is used for debugging, comment or delete it after testing */
print_r($a);
```

Comment: All in one line: usort($array, function($a, $b){ return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]); });

Comment: @pmrotule: Only for version> PHP 5.3

Comment: Worth noting that strcmp is case-sensitve. Took me a while to figure out why sorting alphabetically wasn't giving the expected results. I changed the above code to return the following: return strcmp(strtolower($a["name"]), strtolower($b["name"]));

Comment: @Andrew, you can also use the function **strcasecmp** for this. It compares strings case-insensitive. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcasecmp.php

Comment: This works perfectly until you specify the compare method inside the method scope you are using

Comment: $a is ambiguous ...is i s the same array?

Comment: Use 'uasort' if you want preserve index values

Answer (score 18):

`usort` is your friend:

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
        return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}

usort($array, "cmp");
```

Comment: if we want age then what change will be made in function of cmp instead of strcmp?

Comment: @BhavinThummar Simply `return $a["age"] - $b["age"]`.

Comment: Thanks @ccKep. I have solved my issue using this solution.