# Sort Multi-dimensional array by value dynamically with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

This Stackoverflow answer is 95% of the way there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10484863.  I just need to pass another variable into the function which I believe uses closure.

I want to pass the variable sort:

```
$sort = get_category_name();
```

into:

```
function compareByName($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
}

usort($a, 'compareByName');
```

so its $a[$sort] and not defined by me as $a[key].

My array:

```
Array(
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 7
        [product_type_id] => 2
        [category_en] => Prints
        [category_es] => Impresiones
        [category_ru] => Печати
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => 8
        [product_type_id] => 2
        [category_en] => Drawings
        [category_es] => Dibujos
        [category_ru] => Рисунки
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 9
        [product_type_id] => 2
        [category_en] => Paintings
        [category_es] => Pinturas/Cuadros
        [category_ru] => Картины
    )
)
```

should allow me to sort the array by the category based on the users language which is set by get_category_name().

Comment: Can you be more specific? How are we supposed to use `get_category_name()`?

Comment: get_category_name will return back 'category_en', 'category_es', 'category_ru', and eventually other languages.  So it returns back the names of the keys in this array that I want to sort by

Comment: So you want to sort by `$a[get_category_name()]`?

Comment: Yes @Passerby.  If I say `category_en`, it should sort the array Drawings, Paintings, and Prints.  If I say `category_es`, it should sort Dibujos, Pinturas, Impresiones.  These are keys a level down in a multi-dimensional array

Comment: Then just use `$a[get_category_name()]`; this is not syntax error.

Comment: I think I tried to make this more complicated than it was.  Just figured it out.  Thanks @passerby.