# Json array sort alphabetically in yii1

Tags: php, arrays, json, sorting, yii1.x

I am stuck with a problem . I have an json array which contains categories,I need the array should be sorted alphabetically based on the category name.
Here is my code.

- Controller

  ```
  $post = file_get_contents("............");
  $model = CJSON::decode($post, true);

          function cmp($a, $b)
          {
              //echo "<pre>  a: ";print_r($a);die;
              return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
          }
          usort($model, "cmp");
          $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));
  ```
- View page

  ```
                              $options = array();
                                  foreach ($model as $user) :

                                      foreach($user as $use):

                                          $options[$use['id']] = $use['name'];

                                      endforeach;
                                  endforeach;

                          echo CHtml::dropDownList('mySelect', 'name', $options,array('prompt'=>'------Select--------'));


                      ?>
              </div>
          </div>
  ```

$model

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => SMALL PATCHES
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => BIG PATCHES
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => CUSTOM PATCHES
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => EVENT PATCHES
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => BLANK PATCHES
                )

            [5] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => USS PATCHES
                )

            [6] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 7
                    [name] => FLAGS
                )

        )

)
```

Please help me with this... Waiting for a response....

Comment: can you show your array `$model` ?

Comment: once go through [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) **Example 2**

Comment: i referred http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484607/php-sort-array-alphabetically-using-a-subarray-value

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer i just made a small change

Controller

```
$post = file_get_contents("...........");
        $model = CJSON::decode($post, true);

        function cmp($a, $b)
        {
            return strcmp($a["name"], $b["name"]);
        }
        uasort($model['categories'], "cmp");
        $this->render('index',array('model'=>$model));
```