# Sorting JSON/Array in alphabetical order using multiple values in jQuery or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following problem:
As you can see on the picture, I have a drop down box that is not sorted alphabetically by country or city.

The `JSON object` looks like this:

```
[{"HAM": {Name: "Hamburg", Country: "Germany", ...}, 
   "DEL": {Name: "Delhi", Country: "India", ...}, etc.}]
```

In `PHP` it is assembled inside a loop as follows:

```
$locations[$locationCode] = [
                'name' => $locationName,
                'type' => $locationObject->getType(),
                country' => $this->getCountryForLocation($locationName),
                'accessSizes' => $accessSizes,
                'services' => $services
        ]
```

How can I sort the countries alphabetically first and then the cities in `jQuery` or `PHP`? I would prefer to do this in `PHP`.

My problem is that I try it outside the loop and so I don't know the `$locationCode` anymore. Can anyone help me? I tried `array_multisort()` to bypass the `$locationCode` but unfortunately it never worked.

Comment: You need to show what you have tried.. but ultimately its most likely a dupe of [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value) or [PHP sort array alphabetically using a subarray value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484607/php-sort-array-alphabetically-using-a-subarray-value/10484863) +3k [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+sort+multidimensional+array+by+value+alphabetically+site:stackoverflow.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP has two neat array sorting functions called [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) (use this if you want to preserve the keys) either of which allows you to write custom functions to sort arrays any way you like.

```
<?php

$c = array();
$c["HAL"] = array("City" => "Hamlet", "Country" => "USA");
$c["HUS"] = array("City" => "Houston", "Country" => "USA");
$c["HAN"] = array("City" => "Hannover", "Country" => "Germany");
$c["HAM"] = array("City" => "Hamburg", "Country" => "Germany");

echo "Before Sorting:\r\n<pre>" . print_r($c, true) . "</pre>";
usort($c, "cmp");
echo "After Sorting:\r\n<pre>" . print_r($c, true) . "</pre>";

function cmp ($a, $b) {
    $cmp = strcmp($a["Country"], $b["Country"]);
    if ($cmp == 0) $cmp = strcmp($a["City"], $b["City"]);
    return $cmp;
}

?>
```