# Stable sort array using second dimension key

Tags: php, sorting

I have to use a webservice which return JSON. After decode JSON I get array:

```
$arrays[0]["2013-04-09"]=$someValue;
$arrays[1]["2013-04-09"]=$someValue;
$arrays[2]["2013-04-11"]=$someValue;
$arrays[3]["2013-04-05"]=$someValue;
$arrays[4]["2013-04-09"]=$someValue;
```

I want sort (stable way and using key of second dim key) array and get as result:

```
$arrays[3]["2013-04-05"];
$arrays[0]["2013-04-09"]; //stable way don't swap with next val
$arrays[1]["2013-04-09"]; //stable way don't swap with next and prev vel
$arrays[4]["2013-04-09"]; //stable way, don't swap with prev val
$arrays[2]["2013-04-11"];
```

Can you help me? I try create own function of sort beacause ksort or krsort sort using only first dim key. Thank you for answers.

EDIT:
I try write my own function - and this works - I got wrong "valid answers" in my units test and this is reason that I said that this isn't works:

```
private function getResult(){
...
usort($arrays,array($this,'mycmp'));
...
}
private function mycmp($a, $b){
    foreach($a as $key=>$val){
        $first = $key;
    }
    foreach($b as $key=>$val){
        $second = $key;
    }

    if ($first == $second){
        return 0;
    }
    return ($first < $second) ? -1:1;

}
```

THANKS FOR HELP

Comment: What other keys does the structure have? If there's only one key (the date) in the sub-arrays, it should be fairly straightforward. Post some example JSON to help the answer along.

Comment: I just had a perfect answer before realising your keys are different. Do you want to sort by key or by value of your second dimension?

Comment: FYI: It'd be [this sort of approach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value), but using the key rather than the value. Hence my question above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that each of the sub-arrays has the date key in the same place (e.g. always first key in the object), you could do the following:

```
$keyPosition = 0; // location of the key in the array structures

usort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($keyPosition) {
    $aKeys = array_keys($a);
    $bKeys = array_keys($b);

    return strcmp($aKeys[$keyPosition], $bKeys[$keyPosition]);
});
```

**However**, what you should be aware is that [PHP no longer supports stable sorting](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53341), so you may not get exactly the same ordering as previous. If this is an absolute requirement, you may need to roll your own sort function. [Here's a Gist that might help](https://gist.github.com/olvlvl/1574867).