# Sorting Dates inside Array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have this array

```
$array = array(
array(
"start" => "2013-12-22",
    "end" => "2013-12-25"
),
array(
"start" => "2013-12-30",
    "end" => "2013-12-31"
),
array(
"start" => "2013-11-28",
    "end" => "2013-11-30"
),
array(
"start" => "2014-07-12",
    "end" => "2014-07-18"
),
array(
"start" => "2014-08-01",
    "end" => "2014-08-07"
)
);
```

i want to short the dates based on "start" date ascending. so I use this usort to do that

```
function sortFunction($a, $b) {
            return strtotime($a['start']) - strtotime($b['start']);
        }

        usort($array, "sortFunction");

print_r($array);
```

but I got following message, and the dates not sorted.

```
PHP Warning:  usort() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback, function 'sortFunction' not found or invalid function name
```

how to do it properly?

thank you guys

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value)

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `"start" => "2013-12-22"` and so on? You may read more about PHP [arrays](http://php.net/arrays) and then rewrite your question.

Comment: Do you do this within another function or class ? sortFunction is supposed to be a global function.

Comment: sorry I wrote array wrong. I still got message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think u define 'sortFunction' out of the scope where You call usort($array, "sortFunction");

You have to define and implement 'sortFunction' in the same method or scope where you call usort($array, "sortFunction");

Alternatives:

Use this:

```
usort($array,function ($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a['start']) - strtotime($b['start']);
    });
```

Instead of

```
function sortFunction($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a['start']) - strtotime($b['start']);
    }

    usort($array, "sortFunction");
```