# Sort by php array

Tags: php, sorting, date

I need to sort the notification array by the value 'start_date' DESC order from the getNotifications function:

```
$posts_id_arr = getPoststIds($conn);

foreach ($posts_id_arr as $key => $val) {
  $total_arr[$key] = [
    'notification' => getNotifications($val['post_id'], $user_id, $conn)
  ];
}

$response_array = array('data' => $total_arr, 'more things' => $more_array);
echo json_encode($response_array);
```

right now the order is by post id due to the foreach loop.

```
data {
       notification: 
      [
       {
        post_id: “1",
        start_date: "2016-10-10 08:00:00",
       },
       {
        post_id: “1",
        start_date: "2016-10-10 12:00:00",
       }
    ],
     notification:
      [
        post_id: “2",
        start_date: "2016-10-10 09:00:00",
       },
       {
        post_id: “2",
        start_date: "2016-10-10 13:00:00",
       }
    ]
}
```

And i need it to be 1: 08:00, 2: 09:00, 1: 12:00, 2: 13:00

Comment: I think you should sort the data after the loop, that would be helpful and takes less iteration.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value)

Comment: @Gilad Adar. Have you tried with my solutions. If not try and share thought and if you face any hindrance let me know so that we shall rectify it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a custom function to sort the values in the array using [uasort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php). Your date format is sortable using `strcmp` - a date in the past is lower than a date in the future, so you can use this in your comparator.

```
function sort_by_date($a, $b) {
  return strcmp($a->start_date, $b->start_date);
}

$sorted_posts = uasort($total_arr->notification, 'sort_by_date');

$response_array = array('data' => $sorted_posts, 'more things' => $more_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort with the inner array you can better prefer for the `usort()` method.

usort — Sort an array by values using a user-defined comparison function

This function will sort an array by its values using a user-supplied comparison function. If the array you wish to sort needs to be sorted by some non-trivial criteria, you should use this function.

```
<?php
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    return strcmp($a["fruit"], $b["fruit"]);
}

$fruits[0]["fruit"] = "lemons";
$fruits[1]["fruit"] = "apples";
$fruits[2]["fruit"] = "grapes";

usort($fruits, "cmp");

while (list($key, $value) = each($fruits)) {
    echo "\$fruits[$key]: " . $value["fruit"] . "\n";
}
?>
```

When sorting a multi-dimensional array, `$a` and `$b` contain references to the first index of the array.

The above example will output:

```
$fruits[0]: apples
$fruits[1]: grapes
$fruits[2]: lemons
```

**Alternative Solution:**

You can try `array_multisort()` since it will sort the array based on the order that you need.

```
$arr  = your array;
$sort = array();
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $sort['field'][$k] = $v['field'];
}

array_multisort($sort['field'], SORT_DESC, $arr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: the "fruits" (posts_id_arr) is not the issue, i need to sort the total_arr

Comment: I think He need to sort the full array, And that could be applicable only after the for loop.

Comment: ya if he is Trying to sort the full array. He can sort using `ksort` right. But if he is trying to sort the inner array alone he can do `array_multisort()` But it is advisable to get the output and then sort in the order he wants right.

Answer (score 0):

However, you don't need to perform the sort inside the `foreach`.

You can try the below code. Change the variable name accordingly.

```
foreach ($points as $key => $val) {
    $time[$key] = $val[0];
}

array_multisort($time, SORT_ASC, $points);
```

This is because of the way `array_multisort` works. It sorts multiple arrays, and when the `$time` array is sorted, the $points array is re-ordered according to the array indices in $time. The array_multisort should come after the foreach, though
Hope this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps:

1) Define a temporary array to store the dates:

```
foreach ($total_arr['notification'] as $vals) {
    $temp_dates[] = $vals['start_date'];
}
```

2) Sort the newly created temp array using [`arsort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.arsort.php):

```
arsort($temp_dates);
```

3) Use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and loop to find corresponding post ids and store to resulting array:

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($total_arr['notification'] as $vals) {
    $res['notification'][] = array_filter($vals, function($val) {
        return $val['start_date'] == $temp_dates[$i];
    });
    $i++;
}

$response_array = array('data' => $res, 'more things' => $more_array);
```

Note: Not sure if it works with duplicate `start_date`s.

Comment: got null for some reason.

Comment: Does `total_arr` directly have `notification` as key? Or does it have upper indexes before `notification`?

Answer (score 0):

As iblamefish mentioned, using `uasort()` is the way to go - it is simple an both memory and processing efficient, compared to all the other answers. But while `strcmp()` does produce good results for the SQL-style dates that you have, it is not the "correct" way to handle time fields - you should parse the times and compare them as time values:

```php
$a = [
  [ "name" => "foo", "date" => "2016-08-09 10:30:00" ],
  [ "name" => "bar", "date" => "2016-01-09 02:00:00" ],
  [ "name" => "baz", "date" => "2016-11-02 18:21:34" ]
];
uasort($a, function($a,$b) {
  return (new DateTime($a->date))->getTimestamp() - (new DateTime($b->date))->getTimestamp();
});
var_dump($a);
```

produces:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    'name' =>
    string(3) "foo"
    'date' =>
    string(19) "2016-08-09 10:30:00"
  }
  [1] =>
  array(2) {
    'name' =>
    string(3) "bar"
    'date' =>
    string(19) "2016-01-09 02:00:00"
  }
  [2] =>
  array(2) {
    'name' =>
    string(3) "baz"
    'date' =>
    string(19) "2016-11-02 18:21:34"
  }
}
```

Also, closures (anonymous functions) are more fun than using old-style "text callables").