# PHP - How to sort an array by subvalue with differing keys?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have read up on the following which shows how to sort an array by subvalue when the key is the same. [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value)

I need something like the following:

```
function cmp_by_optionNumber($a, $b) {
return $a["$key"] - $b["$key"];
}

...

usort($array, "cmp_by_optionNumber");
```

However I need to sort by value when the key is different each time? What is the best way to go about this?

```
Array
(
[Example1] => Array
    (
        [RabbitRabbit] => 91
    )

[Example2] => Array
    (
        [DogDog] => 176
    )

[Example3] => Array
    (
        [DuckDuck] => 206
    )
)
```

I want sorting to be:

```
Array
(
[Example3] => Array
    (
        [DuckDuck] => 206
    )

[Example2] => Array
    (
        [DogDog] => 176
    )

[Example1] => Array
    (
        [RabbitRabbit] => 91
    )
)
```

EDIT! Using the following code erases the parent key name!

```
return array_shift(array_values($b)) - array_shift(array_values($a));


Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [DuckDuck] => 206
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [DogDog] => 176
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [RabbitRabbit] => 91
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first element of an array using

```
$first = array_shift(array_values($array));
```

So you'll get something like this :

```
function cmp_by_optionNumber($a, $b) {
    return array_shift(array_values($a)) - array_shift(array_values($b));
}
```

Comment: Thanks makes a lot of sense but then I have lost the parent key, please see my edit!

Comment: So you can use uasort to keep indexes, and to sort it from largest to smallest use return array_shift(array_values($b)) - array_shift(array_values($a));

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) like this:

```
function compare_options($x, $y) {
  return $x["optionNumber"] - $y["optionNumber"];
}

usort($arr, "compare_options");
var_dump($arr);
```

In PHP 7 or greater, [`<=>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php/31298778#31298778) operator can be used like this:

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) {
    return $x['optionNumber'] <=> $y['optionNumber'];
});
```

Hope this helps!