# How to sort an Associative array in PHP by specific value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

Here is my Array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [MyProduct] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5681
                    [part_number] => 78689
                    [model] => Tiger Paw GTZ All Season
                    [web_price] => $74.68
                    [web_price_markup] => 91.07

                )
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [MyProduct] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 33370
                    [part_number] => 49946
                    [model] => Tiger Paw GTZ A/S 2
                    [web_price] => $75.92
                    [web_price_markup] => 92.58
                )
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [MyProduct] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 12542
                    [part_number] => 28953781
                    [model] => Ziex ZE950 A/S
                    [web_price] => $78.86
                    [web_price_markup] => 96.17                    
                )
        )       
)
```

I want to sort this array by "web_price_markup", please help.

Comment: `usort()` and a comparator.

Comment: Please refere this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282413/sort-array-of-objects-by-object-fields

Comment: This question translates to: “I don't want to do my work, please solve this problem for me, as I'm lazy.”

Comment: Possible duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: duplicated question. please read the following.
[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value)

Comment: @feeela, thank you for the translation, for me its just one of the day when you try but nothing is working. thanx..!

Answer (score 0):

First of all write comparer function which compares `'web_price_markup'` values of your object.

```
function compare($a,$b){   return strcasecmp($a['name'], $b['name']); }
```

and then use [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) (assume that your array is `$x`):

```
if(usort($x, 'compare')){
         var_dump($x);
    }
```