# Sort array by highest possible subarray value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a question similar to this one: [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value) however it is a bit different since I want to find/search for the highest of many subarray values and sort the "main" array after that.
Below is the array structure I have, with groupings that contain a number of subitems where each subitem has a score.

```
Array
(
    [grouping1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_score] => 8.2
                    [_source] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Subitem 1111,
                            [ID => 999
                        )

                )

        )

    [grouping2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_score] => 8.546042
                    [_source] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Subitem2222,
                            [ID] => 987654
                        )

                )

        )

    [grouping3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [_score] => 10.163501
                    [_source] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Subitem3333
                            [ID] => 12345

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [_score] => 8.55
                    [_source] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Subitem4444,
                            [ID] => 67890
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [_score] => 9.55
                    [_source] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Subitem5555
                            [ID] => 65421
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I would like to

1. Check the highest score amongst subitems for each grouping
2. Sort groupings after highest available subitem score

The expected output is the containing array to have this order

1. [0] grouping3 since its highest subarray score is 10.163501
2. [1] grouping2 since its highest subarray score is 8.546042
3. [2] grouping1 since its highest subarray score is 8.2

Comment: can you paste that array as JSON?

Comment: Couldn't you delete the _index and _source values? It seems to me they are not necessary for this problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value)

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: Thanks, I removed the _index values and explained the expected output.

Comment: What if `grouping` has items with different `score`, how are they sorted?

Comment: @u_mulder sorry that was unclear - subitems can have different scores like 8.55, 9.55 and 10.1 (edited now). They will be sorted randomly inside the grouping. But the highest subitem score should represent the grouping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, that's what you need to do - find `max` score in each `grouping` and store a lookup `[grouping -> score]`, then sort this lookup array preserving keys and build new array:

```
$lookup = [];
foreach ($source_array as $key => $grouping) {
    $max = 0;
    foreach ($grouping as $item) {
        if ($max < $item['_score']) {
            $max = $item['_score'];
        }
    }
    $lookup[$key] = $max;
}

// sort `$lookup` preserving keys
arsort($lookup);

$sorted_array = [];
foreach ($lookup as $key => $max) {
    $sorted_array[$key] = $source_array[$key];
}
```

Comment: I changed $sorted_array[$key] = $array[$key]; to $sorted_array[$key] = $source_array[$key]; and it seems to be working. Think it's a correct change?