# PHP - Sort array by subarray value based on a second array

Tags: php, arrays

I've done some research including going through [PHP Sort Array By SubArray Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value) but this is a variation:

I have an array as follows:

```
$data = 
[
 0 => [
    'id' => (int) 5,
    'name' => 'Foo',
    'group_id' => (int) 1,
 ],
 1 => [
    'id' => (int) 6,
    'name' => 'Bar',
    'group_id' => (int) 1,
 ],
 2 => [
    'id' => (int) 8,
    'name' => 'Baz',
    'group_id' => (int) 7,
 ],
 3 => [
    'id' => (int) 9,
    'name' => 'ABC',
    'group_id' => (int) 2,
 ],
 4 => [
    'id' => (int) 10,
    'name' => 'DEF',
    'group_id' => (int) 65,
 ]
];
```

I also have an array second array of `group_id`'s that are relevant to a search a user has performed:

```
$gids = [7, 65];
```

What I want to do is order `$data` by `group_id` based on the values inside `$gids`. So the order of `$data` should become:

```
 0 => [
    'id' => (int) 8,
    'name' => 'Baz',
    'group_id' => (int) 7,
 ],
 1 => [
    'id' => (int) 10,
    'name' => 'DEF',
    'group_id' => (int) 65,
 ]
 2 => [
    'id' => (int) 5,
    'name' => 'Foo',
    'group_id' => (int) 1,
 ],
 3 => [
    'id' => (int) 6,
    'name' => 'Bar',
    'group_id' => (int) 1,
 ],
 4 => [
    'id' => (int) 9,
    'name' => 'ABC',
    'group_id' => (int) 2,
 ],
```

Note that once the `$gids` array has been taken into account, the `group_id` of the remaining items in `$data` is numerical (ascending order in this case: `1, 1, 2`).

I understand it's possible to use `usort` and an anonymous function, e.g.

```
 usort($data, function ($gids) {

 });
```

However, I don't understand what to write inside this function to perform  ordering in this way? My initial thought was to do a `foreach($gids)` followed by a `foreach($data)` and compare the `group_id` value. But I don't know what to do in terms of modifying `$data` so that it reorders.

Please can someone help?

Equally, if there is already a post which explains how to do this please let me know, because I couldn't find one on here. The original link simply bases ordering numerically, not on a second array (`$gids` equivalent).

Using PHP 7.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
usort($data, function($a, $b) use ($gids)
{
    $posA = array_search($a['group_id'], $gids);
    if ($posA === false) {
        $posA = 9999;
    }

    $posB = array_search($b['group_id'], $gids);
    if ($posB === false) {
        $posB = 9999;
    }

    return $posA - $posB;
});
```

If found in the array of $gids, the sorting of $gids will be used, else the elements will stay in the order they're given in.

The return I'm getting is the following:

> array:5 [▼   0 => array:3 [▼
>       "id" => 8
>       "name" => "Baz"
>       "group_id" => 7   ]   1 => array:3 [▼
>       "id" => 10
>       "name" => "DEF"
>       "group_id" => 65   ]   2 => array:3 [▼
>       "id" => 5
>       "name" => "Foo"
>       "group_id" => 1   ]   3 => array:3 [▼
>       "id" => 6
>       "name" => "Bar"
>       "group_id" => 1   ]   4 => array:3 [▼
>       "id" => 9
>       "name" => "ABC"
>       "group_id" => 2   ] ]

Comment: This does exactly what I want so many thanks. Please could you explain the significance of `9999` (`$posA = 9999, $posB = 9999`) as I'm not sure why that's used?

Comment: @Andy I'm just using fake values here so that the comparison works. As example, if the first two `1` will be compared, both will use the fake value of 9999. 9999 - 9999 = 0, so the order will remain at it is. It's possible that this could be cut off with remaining the same functionality, haven't tested that one to be honest.