# DB result ordered by nearest matches (3 numeric criterias)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to make a system where I can input multiple values, and get all matches with a 15% tolerance from a mysql table. I've made in HTML and CSS the layout and I've managed to achieve it, but the problem is, I need to get the best match on top!

My table has 4 columns Modelo, L, A, H (Model, Length, width, height)
Here's my code:
**HTML**

```
        <div class="battrac">
            <label for="largo">L</label>
            <input id="largo" name="largo" onkeyup="buscar()" required></input>
            <label for="ancho">A</label>
            <input id="ancho" name="ancho" onkeyup="buscar()" required></input>
            <label for="alto">H</label>
            <input id="alto" name="alto" onkeyup="buscar()" required></input>
        </div>
```

**JS**

```
function buscar() {
 // if (str=="") {
 //   document.getElementById("result-trac").innerHTML="";
 // }
var l = document.getElementById("largo").value;
var a = document.getElementById("ancho").value;
var h = document.getElementById("alto").value;


 var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("result-trac").innerHTML=this.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","busc.php?t="+tipo+"&l="+l+"&a="+a+"&h="+h,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

**busc.php**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
if($link === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$l = $_GET['l'];
$a = $_GET['a'];
$h = $_GET['h'];

if($l=="" ||$a=="" ||$h==""){
echo("Por favor compelte todos los campos");
exit;
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE L>=($l * .85) AND L<=($l * 1.15) AND A>=($a * .85) AND A<=($a * 1.15) AND H>=($h * .85) AND H<=($h * 1.15)";
$result = $link->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
echo('<table style="width:100%">
              <tr>
                <th>Modelo</th>
                <th>L</th>
                <th>A</th>
                <th>H</th>
              </tr>');

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo("
<tr>
<td>".$row['Producto']."</td>
<td>".$row['L']."</td>
<td>".$row['A']."</td>
<td>".$row['H']."</td>
</tr>
        ");
}
echo('</table>');
}else{echo($link->connect_error);}

?>
```

[image: Problem]

In this picture, the nearest match is BAT 2, but BAT 1 is showing up first.

Some IDs and Classes are in Spanish, but if you need any other information, let me know!
EDIT: What I need to do, is to get the nearest match on top. See in the picture BAT 2 has more near numbers than BAT 1 dora's, but BAT 1 is on top. I want BAT 2 to appear on top
Here's a fiddle with 4 rows http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e705f So if I need, for example, a product that has L=95, A=95 and H=95, I would like to have BAT 3 show up first, and then BAT 2 and BAT 1. But not BAT 4 because is not in the 15% tolerance in all values

Comment: If it was me, I'd start with the sql

Comment: Hi! What do you mean by that? Thankss

Comment: How do you define "I need to get the best match on top" ?

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, What I mean is, that I have rows that match best the numbers I input! In the image you can see what I mean.

Comment: @Strawberry, I'll work on it to get something for you!

Comment: Ok but what "match best" means to you?

Comment: @Strawberry, this would be the data I have in my table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6e705f So if I need, for example, a product that has L=95, A=95 and H=95, I would like to have BAT 3 show up first, and then BAT 2 and BAT 1. But not BAT 4 because is not in the 15% tolerance in all values.

Comment: @FelippeDuarte, that would be the row that has the nearest values to the input!

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](https://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](https://php.net/manual/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](https://php.net/manual/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/). [Escaping is not enough!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5741187)

Comment: @Dharman! I'm the only one going to use this, so it's not quite important to secure the script. But thanks for the recommendation!!

Comment: It doesn't matter. Even you can accidently break the site because of this. Please do not neglect this. There is absolutely no reason why you should not be using prepared statements. Please learn to do it right from the start and it will save you from a lot of problems later on.

Comment: @Dharman, I will take your advice! When I solve this problem I'll convert everything to prepared statements!!

Comment: Please edit your question accordingly - this info is too valuable to be buried in comments

Comment: Your query looks good, but I don't understand the rules for prioritizing the results.

Comment: This query will give me the results in the order that are saved. I don't want that! I need it to get the result with the nearest values to the input on top, and then the rest. Thanks

Comment: But you're not defining 'nearest'

Comment: So if you query for 90-90-90 and have 85-85-85, 95-95-95 and 85-100-90 results, which is nearest?

Comment: @FelipeDuarte, in that case, they would all work! The order wouldn't matter there!

Comment: I removed the `JavaScript` and `jQuery` tags for the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's first fix the [SQL-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) issue you have. In `busc.php` you already use `mysqli_connect`, which is good.

The problem is about passing the `GET` values directly in the SQL query. So you need a "prepared statement". Here is a [detailled tutorial](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection).

But before that... And beyond the SQL-injection issue, you certainly will want to ensure the values are numeric to properly query the DB. So I suggest you apply this logic to the 3 `GET` variables:

```
if (isset($_GET['l']) && is_numeric($_GET['l'])) {
  $l= (int) $_GET['l'];
} else {
  $l= 100;  // Default value if unset or non-numeric
}
```

Now try this `mysqli` prepared statement which will result in a `$rows` associative array:
And notice:

- 1. The usage of [BETWEEN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp) here which is a nice alternative to the comparisions you used (make things clearer).
- 2. The `?` placeholders to bind values via the parametric engine of prepared statements.

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM test WHERE 
         L BETWEEN (? * .85) AND (? * 1.15) AND 
         A BETWEEN (? * .85) AND (? * 1.15) AND 
         H BETWEEN (? * .85) AND (? * 1.15)';

$stmt = $link->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("iiiiii", $l, $l, $a, $a, $h, $h);  // iiiiii means 6 integers
$stmt->execute();

$rows = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$stmt->close();
```

Here is a [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb92f3/1) about that `BETWEEN` usage.

So now, the DB results is fetched and the connection is closed. You have a `$rows` associative array which is not sorted as you want yet... There is some additional work to be done on that array and that was your main question.

---

### Your main question:

To each "row" of that `$rows`... Add an additionnal array element to store sum of the absolute the **difference** of each values. That will be used to order the rows in table.

```
for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($rows);$i++){
  $L = abs($rows[$i]['L']-$l);
  $A = abs($rows[$i]['A']-$a);
  $H = abs($rows[$i]['H']-$h);
  $diff = $L + $A + $H;
  $rows[$i]["diff"] = $diff;
}
```

For a `$row[$i]` like `["L"=>90, "H"=>100, "A"=>95]`, and the values sent being `100` for all 3 `$l`, `$a` and `$h` variables,  the `$diff` would be `15`.

So now you will sort `$rows` based on the `$diff` values... Thanks to [that SO anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477524/2159528) about how to filter an array based on a sub-array value.

```
// Sorting sub array SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477524/2159528
usort($rows, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['diff'] <=> $b['diff'];
});
```

And finally... Echo the table:

```
echo('
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
    <th>Modelo</th>
    <th>L</th>
    <th>A</th>
    <th>H</th>
    <th>diff</th>  <!-- Added for debugging... Don't show it! -->
  </tr>
');

for($i=0;$i<sizeOf($rows);$i++){  // Loop the "ordered" rows
  echo('
    <tr>
      <td>'.$rows[$i]['Producto'].'</td>
      <td>'.$rows[$i]['L'].'</td>
      <td>'.$rows[$i]['A'].'</td>
      <td>'.$rows[$i]['H'].'</td>
      <td>'.$rows[$i]['diff'].'</td>  <!-- Added for debugging... Don't show it! -->
    </tr>
  ');
}

echo '</table>';
```

I made a [**PhpFiddle**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/a2ic-3wv7) *(hit F9 or the RUN button)* showing the table would be ordered based on `$diff` using that sorting (with a fake associative array).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm not at home rn, but I'll try it as soon as possible and update you!