Sort PHP array by a key value of each item's value
How would one sort a php array in order of a particular key value pair inside the next level down.
Input array
$sizes = [
  'small' => ['name' => "Small", 'x' => 300],
  'x-small' => ['name' => "Wee Small", 'x' => 140],
  'medium' => ['name' => "Medium", 'x' => 500],
  'less-than-medium' => ['name' => "Medium Low", 'x' => 460],
]

So how would one sort the array of $sizes by the x key of each item's child array?

Correct already answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477496/php-sort-array-by-subarray-value
